# Can I tail an http resource?

Tags: http, tail

Is there a way to tail a resource such as http://someserver.com/logs/server.log ?

This is what I would do for a local file.

```
tail -F /var/logs/somefile.log
```

I would like something similar to that for a file accessed through the http protocol

Comment: No. Theoretically, you could hack something together using byte offsets and curl or wget, but it'd be horrible. What are you trying to achieve? Perhaps there's a better way,

Comment: I have a logfile on a url which is my only way to access it. I want a nice way to view it in real-time

Comment: Go for Log Management tools like Logstash ,Awstats, Webalyzer or Splunk..

Comment: I home somebody already tested [url-tail](https://github.com/maksim07/url-tail)

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to perform a "tail -f" from an url?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31293629/95735), [Tail a text file on a web server via HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6189549/95735), [tail -f equivalent for an URL](https://superuser.com/q/514066/664), [How to tail file from url without downloading the entire file?](https://superuser.com/q/1267867/664)

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a simple bash script to fetch URL content each 2 seconds and compare with local file `output.txt` then append the diff to the same file

I wanted to stream AWS amplify logs in my Jenkins pipeline

```sh
while true; do comm -13 --output-delimiter="" <(cat output.txt) <(curl -s "$URL") >> output.txt; sleep 2; done
```

don't forget to create empty file `output.txt` file first

```sh
: > output.txt
```

view the stream :

```sh
tail -f output.txt
```

**Better solution:**

I found better solution using wget here:

```sh
while true; do wget -ca -o /dev/null -O output.txt "$URL"; sleep 2; done
```

https://superuser.com/a/514078/603774

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$(mktemp)
trap 'rm $file' EXIT

(while true; do
    # shellcheck disable=SC2094
    curl --fail -r "$(stat -c %s "$file")"- "$1" >> "$file"
done) &
pid=$!
trap 'kill $pid; rm $file' EXIT

tail -f "$file"
```

It's not very friendly on teh web-server.  You could replace the `true` with `sleep 1` to be less resource intensive.

Like `tail -f`, you need to `^C` when you are done watching the output, even when the output is done.

Comment: You don't need to stat the file. From `man curl` – *-C Continue/Resume a previous file transfer at the given offset. Use "-C -" to tell curl to automatically find out where/how to resume the transfer. It then uses the given output/input files to figure that out.*

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying `htail` (https://github.com/vpelletier/htail) and it seems to do the job pretty well.

Comment: this looks perfect.. but how do you use it?

Comment: since it's a python script, you can install it via python/pip: https://pypi.org/project/htail/ and then use it just like you would use `tail`

Answer (score 0):

You might use the script from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1102346/401005 if you are able to run php scripts. You should add a `flush();` after the `echo`.

When using `curl --no-buffer http://the/url` you should have an suitable output

Comment: -1 This just downloads the resource and quits. Tailing means keeping an eye on the growing resource and retrieving new content when it appears.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a sentinel program type like I needed ( only update when you respond )

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    echo "y to curl, n to quit"
    read -rsn1 input

    if [ "$input" = "y" ]; then
        curl $1
    elif [ "$input" = "n" ]; then
        break
    fi
done
```

Then run `curlTail.sh http://wherever`

You'll get

```
18:02:44] $: ~ \> curlTail.sh http://wherever
y to curl, n to quit
```

When you hit y, it'll curl it, then prompt you again.

Comment: -1 This just downloads whole resource each time. Tailing means keeping an eye on the growing resource and retrieving **new** content when it appears.